# Webpack of dev dependencies?

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, create-react-app

in NPM, when starting the simplest of web application, such as with create-react-app, I get tens of thousands of files on the node_modules directory. The app doesn't use any of those as it is just a skeleton. My understanding is that the dependencies as just for the development stage.

my question is: is there a way to compact and webpack all of those files so that there are only a few left?

Comment: I think Webpack is clever enough to only include the files you need.

Comment: The contents in `node_modules` reflect the package dependencies listed in `package.json`. The packages are split between `dependencies` and `devDependencies`, and most of the packages will be in the latter.

Answer (score 0):

To use Webpack to somehow bundle all the dependencies wouldn't be possible and would serve no purpose.

And, yes most of those dependencies are used only during local development and not in production when you deploy the app. So you don't have to worry about it.

If your concern is disk space because:

- you may have limited storage capacity
- or, you want to check in the dependencies to source control

You can experiment with:

- use yarn instead of npm, search for `yarn --flatten`
- use a tool like [modclean](https://github.com/ModClean/modclean)